# Do i need to use threadPool.awaitTermination after future.get();

Tags: java, multithreading

I am using the ExecutorService to create a Thread Pool. After adding all tasks, the threadPool is shutdown.

Now the Java Doc for [Future.get()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28%29) says

> Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.

I am not able to understand the "if necessary" part. When does the future.get() method wait and how much time will it wait?
If it waits till the thread execution is over, is there a need threadPool.awaitTermination?

```
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);
List<Future<?>> futureObjList = new ArrayList<Future<?>>();
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
    ...
    Future<?> future = threadPool.submit(myThread);
    futureObjList.add(future);
    ...
}
threadPool.shutdown();

for(Future<?> future : futureObjList){
    try {
        future.get();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        //if any thread fails, all other thread should stop their execution.
        threadPool.shutdownNow();
    }
}

try {
    threadPool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
} catch (InterruptedException e1) {
    throw e1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "if necessary" just means that the `get()` method might block or not depending if the thing that is happening in the `Runnable` or `Callable` is already done or not.

Suppose you submit a Callable to an executor service. The `Callable` takes 2 seconds to execute.

If you call `get()` 1 second after the submit, the `get()` will block for 1 more second. However, if you would have called `get()` 5 seconds after the submit, the get() would not block and immediately return.

Answer (score 1):

```
future.get()
```

will block calling thread, if method *.call* of *Callable* haven't returned a result by the time *.get* is invoked. If you iterate over every future, then by the time you exit a for-loop, all threads have finished executing.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to call `threadPool.awaitTermination()` before getting the results from the threads as awaitTermination will wait for all the threads to complete computation. After all threads have completed you can be sure that `future.get()` will not block as it has completed its execution. `future.get()` will wait until the thread finishes execution unless you specify  a timeout.

Comment: Suppose i have 10 threads. All Threads takes random amount of time to complete. Consider the 4th or 5th Thread throws a RuntimeException. Now if i am iterating over the future objects then it will catch the exception and the rest of the threads will be closed. But if i await for Termination it wont exist till all threads have completed.

Comment: If your requirement is to stop all threads if any thread fails, then it makes sense having the loop. In this case you do not require awaitTermination() anywhere as the threads will have finished executing after the loop is finished. But this is unreliable as by the time you reach a thread that fails, all the others might have already completed and there would be no point shutting them down. You might have to consider having a flag if any thread fails that can be used to shutdown all other threads if set.